# Thousands separator in PowerApps Form

Tags: powerapps

We are using Powerapps Forms to manage the user input to a SharePoint list. For some labels(fields) in the form it is wanted that a thousands separator is added to enhance readability of numeric values (the value is displayed with separators in the list but not in the Form). Anyone experienced this Before and how /if this could be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to format number with thousands separator, you should be able to use the [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text) function:

```
Text( 12000, "$ #,###" )
```